# Mismatched types: expected &str found String when assigning string

Tags: string, reference, rust

I'm trying to assign variable value (type `String`) based on the number of args:

```
let mut out_filename = "";
let args: Vec<_> = env::args().collect();
match args.len() {
    2 => out_filename = args[1],
    3 => out_filename = args[2],
    _ => panic!("To many params !"),
};
```

And I'm getting

```
src/main.rs:39:29: 39:36 error: mismatched types:
 expected `&str`,
    found `collections::string::String`
(expected &-ptr,
    found struct `collections::string::String`) [E0308]
src/main.rs:39         2 => out_filename = args[1],
```

How to make a match statement where the match value (1,2,3) is just a selector and the returned type is different?  There is no `let var = match` ..

Answer (score 9):

You initialized `out_filename` with a string literal. The type of a string literal is `&str` (or, more specifically, `&'static str`), which is different from `String`.

The simplest solution is to assign `out_filename` to the result of the `match` expression directly:

```
use std::env;

fn main() {
    let args: Vec<_> = env::args().collect();
    let out_filename = match args.len() {
        2 => &args[1],
        3 => &args[2],
        _ => panic!("Too many params !"),
    };
}
```

> [...] what if I wanted to make group of assignments based on args count like inside code block {} ? [...] Is there any way to get working code with basic match without `let var = match {` assign ?

You can simply put some `let` statements with no initializers before the `match` expression and initialize the variables as appropriate in each arm. You'll get a compiler error if you try to use a variable that might be left undefined and, unless you define the variables with `let mut`, you'll also get an error if you try to assign a variable more than once on a particular code path.

```
use std::env;

fn main() {
    let args: Vec<_> = env::args().collect();
    let out_filename;
    match args.len() {
        2 => out_filename = &args[1],
        3 => out_filename = &args[2],
        _ => panic!("Too many params !"),
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks this worked but what if I wanted to make group of assignments based on args count like inside code block {} ?:
`match args.len() {
    2 => { something;another action;
},`
Is there any way to get working code with basic match without `let var = match {` assign ?

Answer (score 4):

As Francis Gagné mentioned, `String` and `&str` are not the same. The easiest way to convert them is to just use `to_string()`. It isn't *always* the best thing to do, but it will do while you are just learning because it will mostly work. [You can read more about strings here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/strings.html).

```
let mut out_filename = "".to_string();
let args: Vec<_> = env::args().collect();
match args.len() {
    2 => out_filename = args[1].clone(),
    3 => out_filename = args[2].clone(),
    _ => panic!("To many params !"),
};
```

Note, I also fixed another error you would have come across, because of moving a value out of `args`. Explicitly cloning them, as I have done above, is one way of fixing that, and probably the easiest because you won't have to worry about lifetimes either.